# What is the meaning of "does is"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I have read this sentence and can not get "does is" meaning.   Which type of grammar is it?

> [Couchsurfing](http://www.couchsurfing.org/) is a fairly new website, and what it does is it allows travelers from different parts of the world to meet people in the destinations they're going to. People offer a couch in their home or perhaps space on their floor, and in return  you're expected in your own hometown to offer the same kind of things to people who  might visit you.

Comment: Pratik, quotations should be prefaced with a > symbol at beginning of a line, and not by Code formatting.

Comment: The '*and what it does is*' in this sentence is overly wordy and unnecessary.  It can be replaced with '*that*' with no change in meaning.  "*... is a fairly new website* that *allows travelers...*"

Answer (score 2):

No mystery: “what it does” is just the subject of the clause whose verb is “is”.

Your question is like asking what “enters wins” means in “The person who first enters wins the privilege of getting a pie in the face.”

Comment: Can you give more  example?

Comment: @Pratik “What it does is it gives you something to ask questions about.”